# Print textbox values to a table on printdocument

Tags: vb.net

I need to print a document containing texts and tables. I'm ok with printing the text but i have searched alot how to print a table and I found nothing. I want to put values from the textboxes in cells on the printed table.

```
Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    DirectCast(PrintPreviewDialog1, Form).WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
    PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()

End Sub

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage

    Dim printtext As String = vbCrLf + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + _
"File Number        : " + TextBox1.Text + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + _
"Company Name : " + TextBox2.Text + vbCrLf + vbCrLf + _
"Description         : " + TextBox3.Text + vbCrLf + vbCrLf
    ' Do something e.g.
    e.Graphics.DrawString(printtext, New Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Bold), _
      Brushes.Black, 10, 10)
    e.HasMorePages = False

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated. Cheers

Comment: `e.Graphics.DrawRectangle`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `e.Graphics.DrawRectangle` with `e.Graphics.DrawLine`

You may also find these articles useful:

[DataGridView Printing](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16670/DataGridView-Printing-by-Selecting-Columns-and-Row)

[Printing Tabular Data](http://visualbasic.w3computing.com/vb2008/16/10.printing-tabular-data.php)